# Flashbuilder can't resolve s:MobileApplication SDK 4.6

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder

I've got latest flashbuilder and SDK 4.6. I've added the mobilecomponents.swc, and mobile.swc to the build path, but error does not go away both for project and newly created project. It does not like s:MobileApplication.  Is this no longer supported.  I noticed that posts on this referred to Hero. Whats up with this? Ive got 30 day trial of Flashbuilder 4.6.  Now I noticed talk about needing Flashbuilder Burrito but that is pre 4.6?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty MobileApplication was only available in early builds of the Flex 4.6 SDK.

You should use either [Application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html), [ViewNavigatorApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ViewNavigatorApplication.html), or [TabbedViewNavigatorApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TabbedViewNavigatorApplication.html).  The wizards in Flex 4.6 when creating a new project should create a main application with one of these files.

Comment: ok. I have another problem, when I run in emulator, I want to enter value into input field but nothing happens.  I can click buttons but not key in values. Keyboard does not come up.

Comment: I don't think the emulator supports a soft keyboard.  You'll have to test that on a device.  But, feel free to open another question on that.